# Google admob "Problem linking app. Please try again later."

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I have published an app on google play store with google console and I want to link my app with admob and play store but after 48h of publishing my app it still says "Problem linking app. Please try again later." when I try and link my app. [image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution ? If yes, please share the solution. I'm also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ma having a similar issue. All I can think of is that either it takes time and with the current situtaion maybe a bit of time indeed.

Most I could do was link adsense to the admob with the ids (this is important I think) on our end.

Then hope and pray.

Comment: I have made an AdSense account but how would I link the ids?

Comment: So you need to connect them I had this issue you can get a response sent with a link to your email then when you click the link it will connect the ids.